# Setting scope for $(this) in QUnit tests

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

How do you setup correct scoping in a QUnit test environment for testing callback functions?

Code to test:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    APP = {};
    APP.callBack = function() {
        $(this).closest("input").val('foobar');
    };

    $(function() {
        $("#button").click(APP.callBack);
    });
</script>
<div>
  <a id="button" href="#"></a>
  <input id="id-for-testing-only" name="test" type="text" value="barfoo" />
</div>
```

Test code:

```
test("try callback with 'this' scope", function() {
    APP.callBack();
    equals($("#id-for-testing-only").val(), "foobar", "should set value to 'foobar'");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you might want to use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to trigger 'click' on button and then check the values, instead of directly calling your callback function, which would not be scoped to the button's `this` when called independently.

```
$("#button").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about in QUnit, but in Javascript in general you do it like this:

```
func.apply((this), [arguments]);
```

for example

```
function foo(x) { return this + x; }

foo.apply(1, [2]) == 3
```

so I would try

```
APP.callback.apply(whateverYouWantForThis);
```

Comment: This is the direct solution to the question. Major kudos. However @mahesh-velaga's idea above is the beter solution for _this_ example. Thank you both!

Comment: I agree, his solution is much more relevant here